# how to save a rss-url to a xml file in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, rss, podcast

The user is supposed to write an podcas rss url and get the information about the podcast. At the same time I want to save the information in a xml-file. I have succeded to save it to a txt file and other files but when I try to save it to a xml file I cant open it. For now I only have a textbox where the user can write the url and then press the button (later I will put a list to display the podcast to the user). when the user clicks the button a file is saved, and as I said, it works fine with a txt file but not with a xml file.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var input = textBox1.Text;

        XDocument feedXML = XDocument.Load(input);

        var feeds = from feed in feedXML.Descendants("item")
                    select new
                    {
                        Title = feed.Element("title"),
                        Link = feed.Element("link"),
                        Date = feed.Element("pubDate"),
                        Description = feed.Element("description")
                    };
        foreach (var feed in feeds)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Skriv");

            using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("hej.txt"))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Title:{0}, Date{1}", feed.Title.Value, feed.Date.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is not working when you try to save it as an XML? You're not showing how you're doing that. The easiest way would be to just call [`XDocument.Save`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: When I'm trying to open the file it says that the document is empty. It does not populate the xml file i guess, but it works fine with other file formats..